# Laravel: passing dynamic table name to model e.g protected $table = "$tablename"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.6

So my code successfully creates dynamic tables of the exact same structure (I need it this way for my own reasons).

However, the problem comes when I want to add data to any of the dynamically created table because I don't have a model for it, the way I have when I normally create tables/models.

So, I was wondering how can I work around this problem?

Can I use this kind of logic somehow?

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class sys_cats extends Model
{
    // I know we can't use variable in class like this
    // but this is just to explain what kind of logic I have
    // in mind. 

     $category = Session::get('catName');

     protected $table = "$category";
     protected $primarykey = 'id';
     protected $fillable = [
     .
     .
     .
```

So I assume, this way, we can use this model to dynamically change table name to the name stored in a session variable.

So we won't have to create a separate model for each of these tables.

Is this achievable? Or I must create a separate model file as well each time when I dynamically create a table in database?

I am sorry, if what I am suggesting is fundamentally wrong or anything related. I am pretty new to PHP and Laravel.

Waiting for your kind suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

better to use  `fluent query builder` [db](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries)

> u can add dynamically table name with insert,update,read,delete
>   operation

for example

> get record from db

```
DB::table($tableName)->all()
```

> for insert

```
 DB::table($tableName)->insert(['name' => $name]);
```

> for automatically added created_at and updated_at add in migration

```
$table->timestamp('created_at')->default(\DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
$table->timestamp('updated_at')->default(\DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
```

Comment: Thanks. So, how would I change "sys_cats::create($request->all());" query to DB::table('cat1') format??

Comment: @Kashif for insert `DB::table($tableName)->insert($request->all());` for more unserstand read this article https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries

Comment: Thanks that worked. However, isn't it any way I can use the table name dynamically in the models? Because your suggestion works but it doesn't automatically adds "created_at" and "updated_at" fields etc ??

Comment: @Kashif for automatically added in migration table  `$table->timestamp('created_at')->default(\DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
$table->timestamp('updated_at')->default(\DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));`